# How to circumvent the ES6 Class scoping issue with 'this' key word

Tags: javascript, socket.io, this, ecmascript-6

For example in the Class constructor:

```
Socket.on('user:join', onUserJoin);
```

'onUserJoin' is declared as a method of the class but is being called by socket.io so the `'this'` is not my Class. A way to resolve this is to use the `'=>'` function.

example:

```
Socket.on('user:join', (data)=>{
        this.isOnline = true;
    });
```

Now `'this'` is my class, but how do I reference this anonymous function to unsubscribe ?

```
socket.removeListener('user:join', ????);
```

I did try this:

```
let self;
class RoomController {
    constructor() {
    self = this;
    }
    ...
}
```

and reference the self in the methods but the self was being shared across sockets...

naming the anonymous function could solve it but I preferred for my case the bind option.

Comment: You do it the same way as in ES5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
Socket.on('user:join', onUserJoin.bind(this));
```

This ensures that `onUserJoin` has the correct context, which will be the instance of your class.

Answer (score 2):

You can always bind the arrow functions to the names.

For example,

```
class RoomController {

    constructor() {
        this.flag = true;
    }

    // Assign the arrow function to the name `setFlag`
    setFlag = (v) => this.flag = v;
}

let r = new RoomController();

function tester(func) {

    func(false);
    console.log(r.flag);
    // false

    func(true);
    console.log(r.flag);
    // true

}

// Now you can pass the function around, `this` will still refer the object `r`
tester(r.setFlag);
```

Comment: Note that `setFlag = (v) => this.flag = v;` is an ES7 proposal.

Comment: @FelixKling I wonder why babeljs implemented that already

Comment: Because Babel also supports ES7 proposals :) It's just not ES6.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, the home page itself says "ES6 and **beyond**". Is there any other way to achieve what OP wanted in ES6? I checked in IRC, people suggested me to not use `class` and `this` together.

Comment: There really isn't anything new regarding `this` in ES6 except arrow functions. `.bind` is still the way to go. I guess I'm missing the context, but I also don't know what is bad about `class` + `this`  in particular.

Comment: @FelixKling `Because they cause more ergonomically issues than they solve.` was the response which I got when I asked about why they both should not be used together.

Comment: Meh. Maybe someone who doesn't like the class syntax. I don't really understand why some are so opposed to it. It's basically just syntactic sugar. No one forces anybody to use them. It's also pretty generic response, I wouldn't give too much about it.

Comment: setFlag = (v) => this.flag = v; 
Internal Error  SyntaxError: http://localhost:5000/src/app/AppController.js: Unexpected token (91:12)
  89 |     }
  90 | 
> 91 |     setFlag = (v) => this.flag = v;

Comment: @Brett Yes, as Felix pointed out, it is a ES7 feature :(

Comment: What flag in Babel do you need to enable to make it work ?